# How can i filter boolean in object using .filter() method

Tags: javascript, filter

so i want to filter these objects which is true using the .filter() method but i have no idea how to do it properly. Help me please

```
    const male = [
        {'mike':true},
        {'james':true},
        {'katy':false},
        {'taylor':false}
    ].filter()
```

Comment: Consider using a different structure like `{ name: "mike", active: true }`. Dynamic key names are always a pain

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't know the object key, use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get an array of values and use the first entry as the filter

```js
const identifiesAsMale = [
  { 'mike': true },
  { 'james': true },
  { 'katy': false },
  { 'taylor': false }
].filter(o => Object.values(o)[0])

console.log(identifiesAsMale)
```

This will of course only work if each object has one property with a Boolean value.

Comment: Can you fix the code snippet by logging `identifiesAsMale` instead of `male` which is not defined?